# How can I improve a question if its basis is fundamentally flawed?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, post-ban

I recently received a warning that I was close to losing the ability to ask questions on SO some time after a [particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73296591/) received a large amount of negative score (-6) and was deleted for "detail/clarity" reasons.

I've read [the guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) for this sort of question ban (among quite a few others), but I would like more advice as to how some questions can be improved at all. I would like to improve my deleted questions (the noted one was particularly bad), but the question topic itself is problematic.

I was informed in a comment that I should generally only post images when they greatly simplify the explanation of my problem, but I took this as a general "for the future" piece of advice and didn't change the question itself.

Thanks to the comments on this question, I'm now aware that this is a serious issue and wish to convert the image to text.

However, I struggle to improve that question or my others any further, as, aside from an off-topic question, the questions were fundamentally about specific topics which apparently just aren't popular.

For instance, one of them was about how a product's advertised Bluetooth feature could be physically possible, and it didn't get any attention. Others are about similarly specific items (saving data in text write buffers on receipt of a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in Python). My latest question featured several flawed assumptions (such as that C++ is a superset of C, which I'd been told by two different college professors), leading to a rather bad question even once other issues are fixed.

What should I do to improve a question's topic if it's either simply so specific that no one seems able to answer it or if the concepts upon which it was asked were invalid?

Comment: How does the warning not tell you what to do? PS The warning is about more than that post.

Comment: 'I took this as a general "for the future"' No sound reason for that. 'did not come with any comments' But there is downvote arrow mouseover text. Quote what is relevant from elsewhere in your post. What is the result of your research?--How are  you unable to determine the C & C++ specified behaviours or 'difference?  But anyway how is one language even relevant to the other? "under the impression that C++ is a superset of C" No research. PS Deleted posts count more towards limits than non-deleted posts. PS Images of text are bad. Photos of images of text are really bad.

Comment: The way your question here is phrased, you seem to be more concerned about your fears and anxieties, focusing on them.  Don't do that. Focus instead on improving the quality of your question - all that anxious energy and emotional drive-to-worry can be put to good use in learning good practice.

Comment: Also, since you didn't delete the question yourself, you can't undelete it all by yourself. You'll have to ask for it to be undeleted on Meta SO linked above.

Comment: In general, advice given on a question is an explicit request to alter the question to address the issue.  Negative vote are some times give and retracted when advice is acted upon by OP. You said 'I took this as a general "for the future"'.  I have not voted on any of your questions, but I have downvoted image only code with note "replace image with text" (or similar) then upvoted when the OP does so.

Comment: Thank you all, I have addressed your comments and flagged this question for migration.

Comment: I do have to wonder why you never appeared to have followed the suggestions given to you in comments, in particular, converting the image of code into code-formatted text.

Comment: Regarding the C vs C++ thing, any decent tag on SO has _tag usage guidance_. If you hover the mouse over either tag, it will explain briefly what the tag is for. Both of these tags tell you not to combine them unless you have specific reasons. If you click on a tag and then "learn more", you land in the "tag wiki" where the tag posting rules should be explained more in detail. Using the wrong tags isn't usually a reason for having a question closed, but it might piss off people needlessly and attract down votes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was unsure if editing the question would just attract more negative attention by updating it, since there were other issues with my question. That was one of the reasons for this post - did that get lost in editing?

Comment: It's a moot point now, but at the time between when you asked the question and it was deleted, addressing any and all serious concerns over question quality would likely result in more positive and less negative attention to the question.

Comment: Also, that particular question looks to be an updated version of a previous question, since the title stated, "(updated question)" (title text which was correctly removed by another user's edit), one that I'm guessing was poorly received and one that *you* possibly deleted. If so, then that action might increase your risk of entering a question ban, since now you would have two poorly received and deleted question. Better, for question ban avoidance purposes, would be to fix the original question as best possible.

Comment: I had asked a somewhat similar question before, but it was Arduino-specific. This was a new example of a mechanism I not only didn't understand, but was told was impossible and wanted to see how this one worked.

Comment: I have edited the linked question to be more clear and removed the code image. I still feel somewhat bad about the misunderstandings involved in my original statements, but a lot of them were directly from my programming classes, including that C++ is fancier C. I've removed all of those, although I'm still not sure what to do about the tags.

Comment: When you are looking to improve question linked from the meta the bar is really high. Wording like "some said X" without links to reputable source (product/language reference is ideal) will not work, anything that you can try yourself ("Does a similar behavior also exist in C++") should be done and results added to the question (if it is still relevant to the one question that is being asked). Ideally you work out MRE that does not need any extra files (all those .h files are plain text and you can cut and paste till you get working code with just enough lines that show behavior).

Comment: Still 3 question marks in that post. And a vague title that isn't one of their questions. Also 2 are yes or no questions--do you want yes or no as answer? Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. There still seems to be no reason why you mention C or give C code. "similar" means nothing in particular & adding it to a prior description even with an example is vaguer, not clearer. What is stopping you from seeing yourself from the includes? PS Standard #include files are implementation-specific & moreover including one needn't include anything--compiled code must just act right.

Comment: Use quote format for quotes. Give credit, in text, not hidden under a hyperlink.

Comment: The fact is that if one wants to know what one is doing one must read the manuals for all functionality one is using. And research to find & then read corresponding competent documentation & introductions/tutorials. Beware that random web sites, blogs & videos are not such references. Also understand that reading code does not tell one the specification that it was written to meet. PS These software truths are encapsulated in "RTFM" where F communicates to the receiver the unfortunate additional fact that people refuse to do it. But SO/SE Inc think it is rude. They are shooting the messenger.

Comment: I feel more like a dunce - I've always searched for how to accomplish a task, and never realized that there _was_ a manual because it's never shown up. The "also work in c++" and similar were intended to be about existence, but how this feature works and whether I can make use of a similar capability in my own code, since I'm not the compiler and would need to implement whatever assert is using, *if* it works in a way that is useful to me (turns out not in this case, but that's why I asked).

Comment: Also, I got a message "This question is deleted, further editing is not permitted" when I was editing the question the first time. Will I be *able* to fix the additional statements mentioned?

Comment: @RDragonrydr If it is closed but not yet deleted, ["_Closed questions cannot be answered, but can be edited to make them eligible for reopening._"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). The [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also says that "_Closure is not the end of the road for questions; it is intended to be a temporary state until the question is revised to meet our requirements. However, if you fail to do that, or it is impossible to do so, then the question will stay closed and will not be answered._"

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: You can edit your own deleted post if you didn't delete it. (Maybe an edit session open at delete time is required to be aborted.) When ready you can ask about it here like you did & request undelete vote or hammering or flag a moderator if closed by a moderator. You can learn the answer to such questions instead of just immediately asking in a comment by googling SO/SE Q&A. Research/google how to search/google including using 'site:'. And read the [main] & [meta.se] help. Again: Read the manual.

Comment: @philipxy I have addressed the problems you mention in the question. Do you feel that it has been sufficiently improved to try to reopen? If so, when you say "ask about it here" when reopening, do you mean this site or this question?

Comment: By "When ready you can ask about it here like you did" I meant, when you are ready with your SO question you can edit your post or comments about it here at meta.SO like you already did. I don't know why you think you fixed the issues with your SO post described here or at SO. As a start why do you not just construct a MRE (in C, which it is now asking about)? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: @philipxy Argh, my legitimate apologies for that one. I was so focused on fixing my explanation I didn't notice I was now mentioning an additional problem. Hopefully it's now more clear? I've added an example that demonstrates my exact use case. Please let me know if there's anything else.

Comment: Your post is enormous, when you could have just 1 or 2 files with a few lines that include your .h plus a standard .h for printing. I have no idea what you are trying to ask. I am confused after the 1st sentence--what is in what file? All through the rest I often don't know what file you are talking about. I said read a manual or researched authoritative documentation but you quote a web video. Chop it all out & give a MRE with a 1-line main and/or file with 1 function with 1 line. You should have found the C parts of cppreference.com--reference it. I don't know what "do what I describe" is.

Comment: There are conventions/idioms for using #include files, they will be SO faqs, have you been googling things like '"#include" OR ".h" "file" "conventions" OR "idioms" for "C" -"c++" site:stackoverflow.com' etc etc?? Also other conventions/idioms for initialization over multiple compilation units. At SO but also the web at large.

Comment: I've tried clearing up my question again. I hope it is at least a step toward a better question; I have had very little success with the given search terms - I'm not sure what I need to look for in the first place and for whatever reason it kept giving me C++ results instead of C, despite the specifiers. I don't think PIMPL or RAII are relevant, anyway? I did find out how to order my includes, though, so hopefully that helps. As for my own research, I don't know what the C issue I'm running up against is called (or what it's with), and I have had no success in searching it.

Comment: I think my latest attempt at an edited question better explains the reason for my interest in this issue **and** why I'm asking. I now know that my original question was incorrect due to conflating seemingly-similar mechanics, but I believe that the ability to know why they are different in the first place, and hopefully a working solution to the issue, is still valuable. Admittedly, some of the issue could be because I don't know some sort of idiom here, so please be kind if an idiom itself is the issue - it would thus need to stay *incorrect* so someone can explain in the solution.